# Compress with MadZip in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

Hi I am trying to compress to zip using the MadZip : http://help.madshi.net/madZipUnit.htm

The syntax is this:

```
function Zip (zip         : string;                      // full path 
                                const files : array of string;             // full path
                                const zipAs : TDAString = nil) : boolean;  // only name, no path
```

And my code to test is as follows:

```
Zip('test.zip',['code1.txt', 'code2.txt'],'yeah');
```

The error is this:

```
[DCC Error] key.pas(34): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDAUnicodeString' and 'string'
```

What I have to use the third parameter?
Is it ok applied the second argument to the topic of arrays?

Comment: I don't no MadZip from [here](http://help.madshi.net/StringTypes.htm) TDaString seems to be an array of String.

Comment: The 3rd parameter is optional. Have you tried leaving it out?

Comment: Read the documentation on the exact page you provided (**emphasis added**): The first parameter is the full file path of the new zip archive. The second parameter must be an array of the files you want to have zipped into the archive (full file path again, please). **The third array (only file names, please) allows you to store the files into the zip under a different name.**

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: If I read the documentation because I set the link

I try so

Zip('test.zip',['code1.txt', 'code2.txt'],['code1.txt', 'code2.txt']);

and I get this error

[DCC Error] key.pas(34): E2001 Ordinal type required
[DCC Error] key.pas(34): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'string'

Comment: Simply omit the third parameter. That said, the error message doesn't ring true since there are no Integers anywhere, so it's not clear that your reported facts are accurate.

Comment: I apologize for bothering so much but I had tried making the third parameter and the error is so

[DCC Error] key.pas (34): E2035 Not enough actual parameters

And the end is so code

Zip ('test.zip', ['code1.txt', 'code2.txt']);